# how to reshape a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

data frame reshape image:

[image]

I have a data frame like in the image and I want to reshape the first one so the result will be like in the second one.

is there any command for that in pandas or something similar in numpy?

Comment: `df.explode("link_ID2")`; see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

Comment: ...and please post text [rather than](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9332187) images next time, thanks.